# C++ Custom HashTable usage gives SegFault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I had to implement a Linked HashTable for a project. Now I have to come up with an excercise and a solution to it using my hashtable. Everything works just fine, except I get random Segfault errors.

*By Random I mean: It is the same line of code that causes it, but always at different times, calls.*
I tested my code in Atom, Codeblocks and in Visual Studio Code. Both Atom and CB threw SegFault error, but VS Code ran it just fine without a problem.

**NOTE: THIS IS NOT THE FULL/REAL CODE. It's part of a header file that is included in the main.cpp file which is then compiled and ran.**
The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//List:
template<class T>
struct Node
{
  string data;
  Node *next;
};

class List
{
  private:
    Node *head, *tail;
    int length;
    friend class HashTable;
  public:
    List();
    List(const List &L);
    //~List() {delete this;};
    List& operator =(List L);
    int find(string);
    void insert(string value);
    void remove_head();
    void remove_poz(int);
    void remove_tail();
    void clear();
    void display();
};

List::List()
{
   head = NULL;
   tail = NULL;
   length = 0;
}

template<>
string List<string>::findByIndex(int ind)
{
    int i = 0;
    Node<string>* temp = new Node<string>;
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == ind) return temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    delete temp;
    return "-1";
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::remove_head()
{
  Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
  temp = head;
  head = head->next;
  delete temp;
  length--;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::remove_pos(int pos)
{
  int i;
  Node<T>* curr = new Node<T>;
  Node<T>* prev = new Node<T>;
  curr = head;
  for (i = 1; i < pos; ++i)
  {
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
  }
  if (curr)
  {
    prev->next = curr->next;
    length--;
  }
  else cout << "Error" << endl;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::remove_tail()
{
  Node<T>* curr = new Node<T>;
  Node<T>* prev = new Node<T>;
  curr = head;
  while (curr->next != NULL)
  {
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
  }
  tail = prev;
  prev->next = NULL;
  delete curr;
  length--;
}

//HashTable:
class HashTable
{
  private:
    List *table;
    float load, stored;
    int slots;
    friend class List;
  public:
    HashTable();
    HashTable(int);
    ~HashTable();
    int hashFunc(string key);
    int findTable(string);
    int findList(string);
    HashTable& operator =(const HashTable&);
    void resize();    //I need this one
    void insert(string);
    void remove(string);
    void clear(int);
    void clear();
    void display();
};

HashTable::HashTable()
{
  stored = 0;
  load = 0.00;
  slots = 15;
  table = new List[slots];
}

int HashTable::hashFunc(string key)
{
  int g, h = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < key.size(); ++i)
    {
        h = (h << 4) + (int)(key[i]);
        g = h & 0xF0000000L;
        if (g != 0)
        {
            h = h ^ (g >> 24);
        }
        h = h & ~g;
    }
    return h % slots;
}

template<class T>
void HashTable<T>::remove(T value)
{
  int ind = hashFunc(value);
  int findInd = table[ind].findByValue(value);


  if (findInd == 0)
      table[ind].remove_head();

  else if (findInd < table[ind].length)
      table[ind].remove_pos(findInd);

  else table[ind].remove_tail();

  if (table[ind].isEmpty()) occupied--;
  stored--;
  load = stored / slots;
}
```

The function that would cause the segfault:
(This would be called over and over again in a loop till I don't have more elements in my table)

```
string reakcio(HashTable<string>& HT, int tarolok)
{
    const int anyagszam = rand() % 4 + 2; //Min 2, Max 5 anyag hasznalodik
    int i = 0, j;
    string anyagok[5];
    string eredmeny;

    for(j = 0; j < tarolok && i < anyagszam; ++j) //elemek kivetele
    {
        while(!HT.table[j].isEmpty())
        {
            anyagok[i++] = HT.table[j].findByIndex(1); //This line right here is the culprit :(
            HT.remove(anyagok[i-1]);
        }
    }

    const int siker = rand() % 4 + 0; //75% esely a sikerre
    if (siker)
    {
        eredmeny = anyagok[0];
        for(i = 1; i < anyagszam; ++i)
            eredmeny += " + " + anyagok[i];
    }
    else
        eredmeny = "Sikertelen reakcio";
    return eredmeny;
}
```

(Note: only the functions that might be needed are shown here)

Every element of my hashtable, or of my lists is a 10 character long random string value.
srand(time(NULL)) is used before the function call in main.cpp

Any help or advice would be much appreciated, as I'm stuck at this and I really need to move on to the next portion of my exercise, but I can't without this.

The main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "LinkedHash.h"
#include "functions.cpp"

int main()
{
  HashTable<string> Anyagok;
  int tarolok;

  tarol(Anyagok); //Stores the data from file, no problem here, functions.cpp
  tarolok = Anyagok.getSlots();

  srand(time(NULL));
  int i = 1;
  while (Anyagok.getStored() > 5 )
    cout<<reakcio(Anyagok, tarolok)<<" "<<i++<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The LinkedHash.h contains the hashtable and the list, the functions.cpp contains the problematic function.

**EDIT:**
By suggestion I changed out the

```
Node<string>* temp = new Node<string>;
temp = head;
```

part to

```
Node<string>* temp = head;
```

Also removed the delete line.
But my problem is still the same :/

Comment: This shouldn't be the cause of the problem, but you are causing memory leak by allocating nodes and overwriting its pointer by other pointers soon.

Comment: `Node<string>* temp = new Node<string>; temp = head;` is a classical memory leak, you allocate memory and overwrite the pointer to it in the next statement. Also `Node<string>` is invalid, `Node` is not a template.

Comment: I think this is a case of 'not the real code'. Please post the code you are genuinely struggling with, otherwise you are liable to get answers based on the errors in the posted code, not the errors you have in the real code.

Comment: @john This is the real code, I copy-pasted it directly from Atom (I wrote it, don't worry). I'm just confused. We didn't really had any lectures about memory leaks yet, and I'm mainly just guessing what should I write based on information I found online about the topic. This is why I posted the question, so that I can figure out where I'm wrong and improve upon it.

Comment: @Moenish My answer was wrong, and I've deleted it. Your `findByIndex` function is just a memory leak, because temp is always NULL when you perform the delete. So my code is an impovement but not the answer to your problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Moenish It can't be the real code because it doesn't compile, because of the template issues already mentioned.

Comment: @john Ah, you mean the full code? Also, for me it compiles without a problem, but probably because it is just a header file that is included in a main.cpp file which is then compiled and ran. Sorry about that, should've specified it in the question. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Moenish In the code you've posted `Node` is not a template, but your code treats it as if it is e.g. `Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;`. That will not compile.

Comment: @john Opps O.O You are right, it got cut off during copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everything works just fine, except I get random Segfault errors

Then nothing works at all.

A first review show little care to the cornercases in the list class. You need to define a correct behavior for

- operation on empty lists
- operation on first and last element
- key not found during search

Notable errors found:

- remove_head, remove_tail will segfault on empty list. head is NULL. head->next is invalid memory access. Similar errors are all over the implementation.
- `HashTable<T>::remove(T value)` will always remove something. Even if the value argument is not in the hashtable. This is deeply flawed
- findByIndex returning "-1" make no sense. "-1" is a valid input.
- `Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;temp = head;`. You just leaked memory. You need a **pointer** to **manipulate node addresses**. You should not instantiate Nodes to get a pointer. This is not an issue (ie not noticeable) for a small projet, but unacceptable for a real implementation.

Comment: I see, then I need to fix things up. Just a question: to fix remove_head and remove_tail would it be enough to check wheter the list is empty before doing anything? I have a ```isEmpty()``` function (which I think works based on my tests). Something like ```if(!isEmpty()) do stuff``` would be enough to implement?

Comment: Also, if I change the ```remove_``` functions from ```void``` to ```bool``` and return true only if there was an element removed and decrease the number of elements stored in the table based on the boolean value, would it be a better implementation/improvement, or would it be unnecessary?